# React Native - Can not create new project via react-native-cli when react-native version is > 0.55

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg, react-native-cli

I am trying to create new project via react native project via react-native-cli `react-native init ProjectName` and get the following error

> error Found incompatible module info
>
> Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this
>
> Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact

Project can be created with the same command  when react native version is less then or equal to  0.54

```
react-native init ProjectName --version react-native@0.54
```

The following links also did not helped me.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14861

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3227

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve the problem just moment.

the reason is node version problem.

you can install `>10.0` node.

then, `react-native init project` succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue. Following are the steps I took to solve it.

1. Noticed the yarn error occurs due to incompatible node module version. It required node version >= 8.0. For this, I changed the node version using nvm:
   `nvm use 8.0.0`

Note: Check first if you have a installed node version >= 8.0 using `nvm list`. If yes, just use the above command. Otherwise install it by `nvm install v8.0.0`.

2. After this, you might come across similar error for npm. I did not have updated npm version. Install latest npm by `npm install -g npm@latest`

Try to create new react-native project, `react-native init HelloWorld`.